# Aligning features of two raster images without "skewing" either using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, image, move

What is the best way to simply move one raster image, without skewing it, to align with another?

Does this require georeferencing?

I don't want to "tweak" either image. Just to move / shift for alignment of shared geographic image features.

Comment: provided that your rasters are correctly georeferenced and in the correct projection they should line up, no tweaking should be needed. Please add a picture and more details of your datasets

Comment: Thank you, Ian. The two raster images have been brought into GQIS via their default CRSs. Both coordinate reference systems are the same (EPSG:3857). It's simply that the shared imagery, for each one, is just a little bit off. I must admit that I’m very new to QGIS (GIs in general). I find that different geospatial raster images, captured by different municipalities, with the same CRS, are generally not completely aligned (congruent). In this case, there’s about a 24” difference. Would you say that “georeferencing”, by default, is usually necessary?